# How can I make this code-snippet prettier?

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops

I'm looking for a way to shorten this python3 function. The function takes a lot of input variables and checks every variable to see if it's None. Is there a way to loop through all input variables and add the ones that are not None to the params dictionary?

```
def news(self, query = None, instrument_id = None, days = None, news_lang = None, news_country = None, market_id = None, limit = None, offset = None, source_id = None):

    params = {}
    if query is not None:
        params['query'] = query
    if instrument_id is not None:
        params['instrument_id'] = instrument_id
    if news_lang is not None:
        params['news_lang'] = news_lang
    if news_country is not None:
        params['news_country'] = news_country
    if limit is not None:
        params['limit'] = limit
    if offset is not None:
        params['offset'] = offset
    if source_id is not None:
        params['source_id'] = source_id

    self.make_cmd('GET', 'news', params)
```

Comment: Why don't you use `*args`?

Comment: You should go one step back and ask yourself why the function needs so many arguments.

Comment: This looks like it should be the `__init__` method of some _other_ class.  (Going by the name alone, I'm suspicious of `make_cmd`, too.)

Comment: @mkrieger1, I definitely agree with you. It seems that this method, since he is using `self` as first argument, is taking too much parameters, and this is clearly a codesmell.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like all params are being passed directly to the `make_cmd` so why not use keyword arguments:

```
def news(self, **params):
    self.make_cmd('GET', 'news', params)

news(query="Test")
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you are defining a method instead of a function. The following will work:

```
def news(self, **kargs):
    params = kargs
    self.make_cmd('GET', 'news', params)
```

I would like to make an observation, you are passing too many parameters to your method, and this is a clear signal of a codesmell  called [Long Parameter List](https://refactoring.guru/smells/long-parameter-list).

Answer (score 2):

Could this do the job:

```
import inspect

def news(self, query = None, instrument_id = None, days = None, news_lang = None, news_country = None, market_id = None, limit = None, offset = None, source_id = None):
    frame = inspect.currentframe()
    args, _, _, values = inspect.getargvalues(frame)

    params = {}

    for arg in args:
        if values[arg] is not None:
            params[arg] = values[arg]

    return params

print(news(1,2,3))
```

The advantage of this solution is that you don't need to use **kwargs or *args that would allow any parameter name.

Answer (score 1):

If the values of these arguments can not be `0`, an empty list or any thing else that is "falsy" then you can remove all the `if` checks:

```
params['query'] = query or None
.
.
```

Alternatively you can simply accept `**params` and pass it to `self.make_cmd`:

```
def news(self, **params):
    return self.make_cmd('GET', 'news', params)
```

The downside for this approach is that it is less self-documenting and the end user would need to know what kwargs `news` accepts.